# Modify WSDL file in Visual Studio.NET

Tags: xml, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

We have detected some vulnerabilities (Weak XML Schema) in the WSDL file generated when we make a reference to a WebService in Visual Studio.NET

The problem is the WSDL file is auto-generated by Visual Studio and if we try to modify it manually, it causes some problems when we build the project or Visual Studio re-write the xml code and delete our modifications.

What can we do about it?
Thanks

Comment: Your webService is a WCF service or .svc ? or it's a other WebService (java, php ....)

Comment: To Update your WSDL you need To Update your source Web Service (Interface, ObjectData, web.config )

Comment: We use WCF and ASP.NET WebService

Comment: But exactly what do we must update?

Comment: it depend on what you want to update. So what's the probleme with the wsdl ?

Comment: Hi, for example we need to modify some parameters because they causes Weak XML Schema vulnerabilities... to be specific this xml tag:<s:any processContents="lax" />... we need to change to: <s:any processContents="skip" />, but we can't because Visual Studio re-write our code or it causes problems when we build the project

Comment: your question exceeded my skills, I'm not expert in WCF technologie, but as i understand, you need to extend the serialization operation (generation of wsdl). You need to add some custom DataAttribute to your intefrace. May be these links will be useful : [Extending Metada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733065(v=vs.110).aspx). // [Custom WSDL Publication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040(v=vs.110).aspx)